# How do I make an exit for my loop?

Tags: java, loops

This is for an assignment in my class. It is to make an automatic ordering system. I'm still new to Java so everything doesn't necessarily click just yet. I think most things work for the most part but the main thing I am having trouble with is making the loop itself and making an exit for it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Metal {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double PRICE1 = 5.00;
    double PRICE2 = 7.00;
    double PRICE3 = 3.50;
    double PRICE4 = 0.75;
    double TAX = 0.05;

    System.out.println ("Metal Down Your Mouth Menu");
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("1. Black Sabbath Burgers (Hamburgers With Black Buns) " + PRICE1);
    System.out.println ("2. Rack of Lamb of God (Rack of Lamb) " + PRICE2);
    System.out.println ("3. Texas Hippie Collar Greens (Collar Greens) " + PRICE3);
    System.out.println ("4. Pepsi " + PRICE4);
    System.out.println ("Press any other button to stop ordering.");


    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int itemnumber = 0;
    while (itemnumber < 1 || itemnumber > 4) {
    System.out.print("Enter the item number of the item you wish to order: ");
    itemnumber = userInput.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print ("How many?");
    int amount = userInput.nextInt();

        double subtotal = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double price = 0;
        double taxes = 0;
        String name = "";

    switch (itemnumber){
        case 1: name = "Black Sabbath Burgers"; price = PRICE1; break;
        case 2: name = "Rack of Lamb of God"; price = PRICE2; break;
        case 3: name = "Texas Hippie Collar Greens"; price = PRICE3; break;
        case 4: name = "Pepsi"; price = PRICE4; break;
    }
        subtotal = price * amount;
        total = subtotal + total;   
        System.out.print("Price for items: " + subtotal);
        System.out.print("Price Total: " + total);
}
```

Comment: Your loop condition is inverted.

Comment: That started to help me but I can't get it to loop.

Comment: Loop where exactly? If you want to repeat the menu, you're closing the loop body too early. And of course, you'd want to use a `do ... while` loop, since otherwise `itemnumber` is zero and thus is checked before you read a value for the first time.

Comment: I'm trying to loop the item input/amount input part.

Comment: Right. You need to expand the loop body to contain the rest of the code too, then. And you have to use the `do ... while` loop, because you don't have the input yet when checking the loop condition. It's still a bit tricky, though, since you want to repeat the whole thing, but only if there's an appropriate value. There's more ways to do that - simple `if`, `break`, `return`...

Answer (score 1):

This is my first time posting on this site, but I think I found your problem. There are two large errors, indicated by the arrows:

```
while (itemnumber >= 1 || <-- itemnumber <= 4) {
System.out.print("Enter the item number of the item you wish to order: ");
itemnumber = userInput.nextInt();
} <--
```

1) This should be a '&&' not a '||'. You want it to be within the range. Right now the number it reads has to be greater than  or equal to 1 OR less than or equal to 4, which is all integers.

2) You close your loop prematurely. What your code does right now (after the && switch) is it takes numbers 1-4 and keeps repeating the "Enter the item number...." line until you put a number not in the range, then it continues.

The fix: there are a few ways to fix this. My fix would be thus, and the explanation will come after:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Metal {
public static void main (String[] args) {
double PRICE1 = 5.00;
double PRICE2 = 7.00;
double PRICE3 = 3.50;
double PRICE4 = 0.75;
double TAX = 0.05;

System.out.println ("Metal Down Your Mouth Menu");
System.out.println ();
System.out.println ();
System.out.println ();
System.out.println ("1. Black Sabbath Burgers (Hamburgers With Black Buns) " + PRICE1);
System.out.println ("2. Rack of Lamb of God (Rack of Lamb) " + PRICE2);
System.out.println ("3. Texas Hippie Collar Greens (Collar Greens) " + PRICE3);
System.out.println ("4. Pepsi " + PRICE4);
System.out.println ("Press any other button to stop ordering.");


Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
int itemnumber = 0;
System.out.print("Enter the item number of the item you wish to order: ");
itemnumber = userInput.nextInt();
double total = 0;
while (itemnumber >= 1 && itemnumber <= 4) {


System.out.print ("How many?");
int amount = userInput.nextInt();

    double subtotal = 0;
    double price = 0;
    double taxes = 0;
    String name = "";

switch (itemnumber)
{
    case 1: name = "Black Sabbath Burgers"; price = PRICE1; break;
    case 2: name = "Rack of Lamb of God"; price = PRICE2; break;
    case 3: name = "Texas Hippie Collar Greens"; price = PRICE3; break;
    case 4: name = "Pepsi"; price = PRICE4; break;
}
    subtotal = price * amount;
    total = subtotal + total;   
    System.out.print("Price for items: " + subtotal);
    System.out.print("Enter the item number of the item you wish to order: ");
    itemnumber = userInput.nextInt();
}
System.out.print("Price Total: " + total);        
}
}
```

Explanation: In essence, you had like 90% of it. I moved the mentioned '}' to the end here:

```
     itemnumber = userInput.nextInt();
  } <--
```

That way, it loops over this code until the user ends.
Additionally, your loop does not need much fixing. It can be used with the && fix. However, you have to put that top line before the loop.

```
System.out.print("Enter the item number of the item you wish to order: ");
itemnumber = userInput.nextInt();
```

And then you put the same line at the end of the loop to reset itemnumber. What your loop does is if itemnumber is between 1 and 4, it executes the following code. Otherwise, it stops. By checking before you enter the loop, you set itemnumber so that way the loop has something to check. And you put the next input at the end of the loop so that way your program finishes totaling its first execution before moving on to the next.

Additionally, you should move the variable 'total' out of the loop as seen above. If you keep looping over it and resetting it to 0, your total will output 0 every time. Best to keep the creation of total out of the loop, and its modification inside the loop.

Small tip, use System.out.println(); instead of System.out.print(); it puts the outputs on its own line. Looks a little nicer.

I think that covers it. If you want more explanation, I'd be more than happy to give it to you. Java is pretty fun once you get used to it. It just takes time. :D